# React-Select breaking CoreUi functionalities

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, core-ui

I'm using `@coreui/react` with `React-select` the problem is that returning a `Select` element in `scoped slots` breaks `core-ui` functionalities like **searching** & **sorting**

However it works fine if when returning a `<label>` or a `<p>` with text **Ex**: `<label>{item.status}</label>`

**Question**

Why is Select component breaking the functionality ?

Any workaround / efforts are highly appreciated

**Note**

I have tried workarounds like `<p hidden >{item.status}</p>` and then rendering the `Select` component but it does not work

```js
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import { CDataTable } from "@coreui/react";

...

  <CDataTable
    bordered
    clickableRows
    fields={fields}
    hover
    items={[...employeeData]}
    itemsPerPage={10}
    itemsPerPageSelect
    loading={tableLoader}
    onRowClick={(e) => rowSelectHandler(e)}
    pagination
    size="sm"
    sorter={{ resetable: true }}
    striped
    tableFilter={{
      placeholder: "Filter",
      label: "Search:",
    }}
    scopedSlots={{
      status: (item, index) => (
        <td style={{ width: "13%" }}>
          <Select
            id={item.index}
            placeholder="Select Status"
            isSearchable={false}
            className="basic-single"
            onChange={(e) => selectChangeHandler(e.value, index)}
            classNamePrefix="select"
            defaultValue={{
              label: item.status,
              value: item.status,
              color: getBadge(item.status),
            }}
            // name="color"
            // inputValue={item.status}
            options={[
              {
                value: "ACTIVE",
                label: "ACTIVE",
                color: "#2eb85c",
              },
              {
                value: "DEACTIVE",
                label: "DEACTIVE",
                color: "#e55353",
              },
            ]}
            styles={colourStyles}
          />
        </td>
      ),
    }}
  />
...
```

**Edit**

Accepting answers with `antd-select` also if it works with `coreui-datatable`

Comment: Can you add more info like Error Message, Parent Component or JSfiddle code link to understand better ?

Comment: @kkchaitu there is no error message , Simply put the React Select is not getting filtered or sorted by core UI for some odd reason.

Comment: Did you try putting plan Select in place of React-select ?

Comment: @kkchaitu yes i tried putting plain select , it worked perfectly with plain select , However due to styling restrictions i want to use `react-select`

Comment: if you can place your code in https://codesandbox.io/ will help to understand better

Comment: @kkchaitu i tried doing that :( but some dependencies could not get installed so i quit :(

Comment: The react-select component is self closing, which (for me anyway) has been a source of issues in the past when I've tried to render inside something like a table cell. Have you tried encapsulating the react-select in fragments?

`<> <select .... /> </>`

Comment: @TheFunk this does not work

Comment: @Phil same problems when encapsulating your select inside fragments? Do you have any error logs or anything?

Comment: @TheFunk there are no error logs.. functionality is breaking for example `pagination` status is static it does not change on page change that column stays the same `sorting` is not working on that column `searching` is not working either

Comment: @Phil what do your pagination or searching functions look like? Can you post those? What if instead of using the react-select, you create your own component using a regular select, which you indicated works, and then apply a custom style to it? Obviously the ideal solution would be to make react-select work if you're using it elsewhere, but custom styling in one specific location isn't the worst of workarounds until you can look more closely at the functions.

Comment: @TheFunk Unfortunately styling regular `select` components is not possible , Also writing my own custom `select` component is beyond me I think.....

Comment: @Phil Does the answer below help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to put together a codesandbox and also was able to find the reason it does not work, and fix it.

### The Problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-butterfly-itppu?file=/src/App.js

I guess this Select component has some internal state initialised with defaultValue.
Then the table when sorting changes the index(it sorts the data array) and you are using the index as id, so react reuses the same element but is unable to update the value because you are only providing defaultValue.

### The Solution(s):

basically you should use `value` instead of `defaultValue` in the `Select`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-browser-b02xb?file=/src/App.js

OR

add a key based on some unique property of the item (not the index in the array).

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-sky-56vly?file=/src/App.js